# Convert SQL Server query to LINQ lambda query for two different cols from two different table that are related

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have two tables `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B` which are related.

I need to convert this SQL Server query to a LINQ lambda query in C#:

```
SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, b.COL2
FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b
WHERE b.COL1 = A.COL3
```

Actually `b.col1` is pk in table_b and `a.col3` is fk of that in table_a

Comment: Generally, a "please write my code for me" type of question is considered off-topic here. You should include your attempt(s) so users can help you improve on them.

Comment: Probably, these might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638625/convert-sql-query-into-lambda-expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197602/convert-sql-query-to-lambda-expression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854146/how-to-convert-this-sql-query-to-linq-or-lambda-expression

Comment: @JacobH thank you for tip and respond ... but unfortunately in this case i have no idea how to start ..... im new in linq query ..i have done some things but not different cols from different tables

Comment: Perhaps start by reading my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) ?

Comment: @NetMage nice post

Answer (score 1):

[Navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) are powerful:

```
table_a.Select( a=> new {a.COL1 , a.COL2 , a.b.COL2} )
```

Also, you can learn how to write better questions at "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" I suggest to you to read post carefully.

Comment: so how to define that a.b.col2 is for table_b and apply condition on col of table_b ... this is where i confused

Answer (score 0):

var q = (from a in table_A join b in table_B on b.col1 equals a.col3 select new 
         {a.COL1, a.COL2, b.COL2}).ToList();

Comment: OP asked for _'LINQ lambda query'_